# Failing to run ink! e2e tests

Tags: ink, cargo-contract

I am trying to run e2e tests but getting the following error. Example of running the e2e tests of the flipper contract:

```
running 4 tests
test flipper::tests::it_works ... ok
test flipper::tests::default_works ... ok
test flipper::e2e_tests::it_works ... FAILED
test flipper::e2e_tests::default_works ... FAILED

failures:

---- flipper::e2e_tests::it_works stdout ----
thread 'flipper::e2e_tests::it_works' panicked at /Users/sergejsakac/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/ink_e2e-4.3.0/src/xts.rs:294:13:
decoding ContractInstantiateResult failed: Could not decode `ContractResult::events`:
    Could not decode variant byte for `Option`:
        Not enough data to fill buffer


---- flipper::e2e_tests::default_works stdout ----
thread 'flipper::e2e_tests::default_works' panicked at /Users/sergejsakac/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/ink_e2e-4.3.0/src/xts.rs:294:13:
decoding ContractInstantiateResult failed: Could not decode `ContractResult::events`:
    Could not decode variant byte for `Option`:
        Not enough data to fill buffer
```

Rust version: `rustc 1.74.0-nightly`

Cargo contract version: `cargo-contract-contract 3.2.0-unknown-aarch64-apple-darwin`

The weird thing is that on my other Macbook, I have the same version of both rust and cargo contract, and the tests run successfully.

Comment: did you try with the latest stable? I guess nightly can be the problem here

Answer (score 1):

It should work on rust v1.72 and substrate-contracts-node v0.31 with cargo-contract-contract 3.2